# IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 replaces tabs with space characters before "//" comments

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using "IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3" and when I reformat my code, I want to preserve the tabs before my "//" comments in the cases when there is some text before (on the same line) the comment.

In previous versions of IDEA that was possible, but now I can't find a setting for such behaviour (every time I reformat, my tabs are converted to spaces). The "Smart tab" option in "Code Style" is checked.

Thanks in advance!

---

Yes, of course. This is my code:

```
int fieldOne;        // comment1
int fieldNumberTwo;  // comment2
int fieldThree;      // comment3
```

I want my comments to be exactly one below another. The space between fields and comments is filled by tab characters and/or spaces.

I want to keep my comments in the exact same way, but instead of that when I reformat my code I get something like this one:

```
int fieldOne;        // comment1
int fieldNumberTwo;       // comment2
int fieldThree;       // comment3
```

The space between fields and comments is now filled only with spaces.

I'm using "Smart tabs" for my Java source code files.

Comment: I think someone didn't do his homework.

Comment: Mm.. I can't find anything about this one

Comment: Can you post the code sample? Before reformat, after reformat, expected format.

Comment: This seems to me like an extremely edge use case. Using spaces instead of tabs in this case is the common choice in my experience, partly because tabs only introduce complications like this.